# In Mango OS OnNavigatedFrom is called before OnNavigatedTo. How to find work around for this?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two pages (main.xaml and page1.xaml). When button is clicked in home page page1.xaml will be displayed.
In page1 press backkey then press start button immediately. App will go to dormant state. Now resume the app onNavigateFrom is called first. Since i used State in onNavigateFrom method getting invalidoperation exception.

Did any one know work around for this. I pasted the code below

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        if (State.ContainsKey("test"))
        {

        }
    }
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
      //  Thread test = new Thread();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by adding this line before the line, where you are using the 'State'

```
if(e.NavigationMode != System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
```

But still, the actual problem is not solved here. i.e. after resume you cannot go back to MainPage from Page1, because BackStack is removed by the previous BackKeyPress.

Comment: The solution you gave is working great. Now i am not get exception which actually caused big issue. not going back to MainPage is not big issue in my case.